# Visual Studio: Load SQL file from SQL Studio Unit Test

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to set up a Microsoft Visual Studio Unit Testing environment for some of my SQL queries.  My scenario is somewhat backwards to the typical software development scenario.  For any given work product that I work on, I am trying to exercise **ONE** query through different scenarios, by passing in different parameters and comparing results.

My intention is to load my SQL query from a .sql file in each of my unit tests.

**How do I open my SQL file for reading from within my `SqlServerUnitTest1.cs` file?**

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but I strongly advise use tSQLt for SQL Server unit testing. It's recommended framework to do unit testing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving this was complicated, so I will describe the general outline of what I did.  Some of this might have been unnecessary, but at least my instructions will help you understand all the important steps:

1. Create a new solution, and create a new Unit Testing project in it.  (If you're using the Reporting Services, like I am, make a Reporting project alongside it)
2. Import the queries to your testing project, and set the properties to "Copy if Newer" or "Always Copy".
3. Load the SQL file in your test.  I wrote a function of the form:

.

```
public static string LoadSqlFile(string name)
{
  string path = Path.Combine( Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                            , @"sql\" +  name
                            );

  return File.ReadAllText(path);
}
```

which loads the SQL file by its filename. **This is the answer to my specific question.**

4. Write the test (using the UnitTest template, not the SqlServerUnitTest template).  I wrote some code to generate tests from JSON, which makes this easier for the non-C#-users on my team.  In my use case, each test has an undeclared parameter which gets passed in to the test.  The JSON also takes in a list of expected results, which we compare to the result.